# Bauwagen en español: Como es la palabra para un tipo de remolque o trailer de vivienda temporal

Tags: traducción

En varios idiomas hay una palabra especifica para un remolque o trailer de vivienda temporal para los trabajadores, cerca de construcción que muchas veces tambien se usan como caravana (en sitios que se llaman *Wagenburg* o *Wagenplatz* en alemán).

Las palabras en otros idiomas son:

- [*Bauwagen*](https://www.google.com/search?hl=de&q=Bauwagen&ie=utf-8&tbm=isch) (alemán)
- [*Roulotte de chantier*](https://www.google.com/search?hl=de&q=roulotte%20de%20chantier&ie=utf-8&tbm=isch) (francés)
- [*Maringotka*](https://www.google.com/search?hl=de&q=Maringotka&ie=utf-8&tbm=isch) (checo)
- [*Bouwkeet*](https://www.google.com/search?hl=de&q=Bouwkeet&ie=utf-8&tbm=isch) (neerlandés)
- [*Manskapsvagn*](https://www.google.com/search?hl=de&q=Manskapsvagn&ie=utf-8&tbm=isch) (sueco)
- [*Construction trailer*](https://www.google.com/search?hl=de&q=Construction%20trailer&ie=utf-8&tbm=isch) (ingles)

Si busco por una de esas palabras en google images se ve miles de remolques de este tipo:

[image]

Buscando lo por diccionario encontré

- [trailer](https://www.google.com/search?hl=de&q=trailer&ie=utf-8&tbm=isch)
- [remolque de trabajo](https://www.google.com/search?hl=de&q=remolque%20de%20trabajo&ie=utf-8&tbm=isch)
- [remolque de construcción](https://www.google.com/search?hl=de&q=remolque%20de%20construcci%C3%B3n&ie=utf-8&tbm=isch)

Pero todas estas palabras, usando google images, me traen imágenes de todo tipos de remolques. Estoy buscando la palabra especifica en castellano para ese tipo de remolque.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

En España usamos indistintamente "Caravana".

Según la RAE
4. f. Vehículo acondicionado para cocinar y dormir en él, con motor propio o remolcado por un automóvil.

Edito:
Quizás barracón o barraca también pueda aplicarse al tipo de remolque del que has puesto las imágenes.

Comment: Sí, es la traducción que suelen usar en series y películas de EEUU cuando se refieren a cualquiera tipo de vivienda móvil.

Comment: Advierto que en Argentina "caravana" se usa casi únicamente en la primera acepción del DRAE : "Grupo o comitiva de personas que, en cabalgaduras o vehículos, viajan o se desplazan unos tras otros.". Incluso también para grupos caminantes. Ej: http://www.telam.com.ar/notas/201610/166911-protesta-obelisco-caminata-villa-olimpica.html

Answer (score 3):

En México los nombres mas comunes que he oído para este tipo de viviendas son **`casa móvil`** y **`casa rodante`**. En algunos lugares al norte de México y sur de los Estados Unidos he notado que usan la palabra **`traila`**, que a mi parecer es mas [espanglish](http://lema.rae.es/drae2001/srv/search?id=FSeA5UnGUDXX2flaAWz4#0_1) que español, pero al buscar con esa palabra en google se pueden encontrar imágenes similares a las que muestras.

Answer (score 1):

Dudo que exista una palabra específica -y menos universal. En Argentina, al menos, se usa la expresión "casilla rodante" para lo que en USA llaman [travel trailer](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Travel_trailer) o "caravan" : más uso para viajes de recreación que para asentamiento laborales o vivienda semi-estable. 
Algunas variantes para estos usos específicos son "**casillas viales**" o "**casillas rurales**", según el caso ([ej](http://www.mde9.com.ar/)); o "trailer" (en lugar de "casilla"), o "[módulos habitacionales](http://www.patagonlatinamerica.com.ar/modulos-rurales.php)".

Answer (score 1):

Desde España tu puedes usar "Caravana", o "roulotte" (femenino, la roulotte, ) y todo el mundo te entenderá.

Saludos.

Answer (score 0):

He comprobado con la RAE y el Merriam-Webster y sólo caravana parece ser correcta, también es la que más uso.

El Bauwagen como tal es algo bastante alemán, en España se ven más usualmente contenedores acondicionados para albergar un almacén o una oficina o bien caravanas que se usan como oficina.

P.S. Contruction Trailer no lo acepta el Merriam-Webster, imagino que es como si dijeras carvana de construcción.